# swift 4 remove strikethorugh

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsattributedstring

I click on the row there will be a strikethrough, after clicking once I hope to remove the strikethrough

There is a completed degree default value is **false**

let newList = List(name: name, completed: false)

I tried removing the strikethrough with 
cell.listName.attributedText = nil, 
but it will disappear with my text

```
func completeList(_ indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let lists = self.lists[indexPath.row]
    self.lists[indexPath.row] = lists
    if let cell = listTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ListTableViewCell {
        cell.listName.attributedText = strikeThroughText(lists.name!)
    }
}

// 刪除線
func strikeThroughText(_ text: String) -> NSAttributedString {
    let attributeString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
    attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.strikethroughStyle, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
    attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.strikethroughColor, value:UIColor(red: 235, green: 86, blue: 87), range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))

    return attributeString
}
```

TableView Delegate , DataSource

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return lists.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let listCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "listCell") as! ListTableViewCell

    let listItem = lists[indexPath.row]
    listCell.listName.text = listItem.name

    if listItem.completed {
        listCell.listName.attributedText = strikeThroughText(listItem.name!)
    }

    listCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    listCell.selectionStyle = .none
    return listCell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    completeList(indexPath)

}
```

Comment: did you checked my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
let attributeString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
attributeString.removeAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.strikethroughStyle, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
attributeString.removeAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.strikethroughColor, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working
But how do I go to set the remove when clicked once

Comment: create function like similar to `strikeThroughText` and call when you want to remove.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string:  (self.yourLabel.text)!)
attributeString.removeAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
    
self.yourLabel.attributedText = attributeString
```